# sencha touch sort list by Distance

Tags: list, model-view-controller, sorting, sencha-touch, distance

i want to sort a list of Locations by its Distance(displayed in list).
i already have a code that sould work but since i am that new to the whole mvc thing, i am not really sure where to place it to make it work.

Maybe someone can help me:

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation',{
autoUpdate: false,
listeners: {
    locationupdate:{
        scope: this,
        fn: function(geo){
            var haversindeDistance = function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2){
                if(typeof(Number.prototype.toRad)=="undefined"){
                        Number.prototype.toRad = function(){
                            return this * Math.PI/180;
                        }
                }
                var R = 6371; //km
                var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
                var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
                var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
                var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

                var a = Math.sin(dLat/2)*Math.sin(dLat/2)+
                        Math.sin(dLong/2)*Math.sin(dLon/2)*Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2);
                var c = 2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(1-a));
                var d = R*c;
                // KM or MIles
                //return d*0.621371192; //MIles
                return d;
            };
        var store = Ext.getStore('locationsstore');
        store.suspendEvents(true);
        store.each(function(location){
            var lat2 = parseFloat(location.get(geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) { })))||0;
            var lon2 = parseFloat(location.get(geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) { })))||0;
            //var lat2 = parseFloat(location.get('lat'))||0;//try to put geocode on this ish
            //var lon2 = parseFloat(location.get('lon'))||0;
            if(lat2 && lon2){
                var distance = haversineDistance(geo.getLatitude(),geo.getLongitude(),lat2,lon2);
                location.set('distance',distance);
            }
        }, this);
        store.resumeEvents();
        store.filter('distance',/\d/);
        store.sort('distance');//check if it is not done or can not be done somewhere else
        list.setMasked(false);
    }
},
    locationerror:{
        scope: this,
        fn:function(geo,bTimeout,bPermissionDenied,bLocationUnavailable,message){
        console.log([geo,bTimeout,bPermissionDenied,bLocationUnavailable,message]);
        if(bTimeout){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Timed out getting your location.');
        }else{
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error getting location. Please make sure location services are enabled on your Device.');
        }
        list.setMask(false);
        }
    }
    }
 });
 geo.updateLocation();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the Solution.Just adding a Listener to the Navigation/List View should do it. I had too much in the Controller so i decided to put it directly into the View.

Comment: Can you show us what listener did you add? It might be helpful for others who are looking for similar stuff

Comment: I had the whole code up there in a controller. The Problem was solved by putting / moving it to the List View i wanted to have it sorted in like: painted: function(){ ^^code